# Python: function to Add logging for SQL queries to web server

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-workbench

I Need to add logging all SQL queries to database with timings.

> This log should be in csv format with columns:
>
> url
>
> datasource name
>
> SQL content     parameters
>
> username
>
> start time of query execution (accuracy in ms)
>
> end time of query execution (accuracy in ms)

I Need an example for this that How can I do this?

This logfile can be used to analyze timings for execution all SQL queries and optimize most long queries.

Comment: If you need to optimize then why don't you try enable slow log?

Comment: Just need to log all requests to csv file. This file will be used for analysing execution duration sql queries and optimize them.

Comment: how about general log? it logs all the query in a txt file

Comment: I don't know about it.

Comment: Okay, check log doc refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html

Comment: I need a python function to handle all this

Comment: hmm, Then i don't know other than sql 